# TFS 2010 and older versions of projects

Tags: .net, tfs

I have a couple of questions related to TFS and source control:

1) I was wondering if TFS2010 supports older versions of projects, such as projects from Visual Studio 2008, and whether it can build those projects normally.

2) I'm also curious about upgrading. Can I just upgrade my existing TFS 2008 to 2010 without installing the new one separately? If not, how can projects be migrated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to [connect a 2008 client to a 2010 server](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/06/10/connecting-visual-studio-2008-team-explorer-to-team-foundation-server-2010/). It is also possible to perform an [in-place upgrade from 2008 to 2010](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=127730) if desired.